# Cox analysis with a variable exposition with two measures at different times

Tags: survival, cox-model, time-varying-covariate, generalized-estimating-equations

I measured blood glucose for a  sample of 500 participants at baseline and one year after.  My issue is death.

I already did a Cox survival analysis for the first blood glucose with my 500 participants.

What type of statistical analysis should I do for the second measure? It's not the same number of my sample size initial because some people die before the second measure.

So I take the sample size of the second measure to restrict again a Cox analysis for the first measure and compare first and second measure. And I did the mean of the first and second measure to do another Cox analysis.

Is there another analysis that I can do?

Answer (score 2):

You can do a time-varying Cox model. If you specify correctly the model everything works even if some subjects had the event (mortality I assume) or were right-censored before the second measurement of glucose (which I assume is your treatment/exposure). This is because in the time-varying Cox model the cases are compared only with subjects who are event-free at the time of the event (risk-set) and for each risk-set the latest update of the exposure value is used. Of course, the interpretation and the correctness of this method depend on the time axis you use (calendar time, study time, age and so on).

However, it's not straightforward to set up the data structure for this model. If you are working in SAS I recommend having a look at the UCLA website for book-based examples on [Applied Longitudinal Data Analysis](https://stats.oarc.ucla.edu/sas/examples/alda/chapter15/applied-longitudinal-data-analysis-modeling-change-and-event-occurrenceby-judith-d-singer-and-john-b-willett-chapter-15-extending-the-cox-model/). Always on the UCLA website if you work in R you can find [this](https://stats.oarc.ucla.edu/r/examples/alda/r-applied-longitudinal-data-analysis-ch-15/) but also the famous vignettes from the survival package author ([here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/survival/vignettes/timedep.pdf)) titled *Using Time Dependent Covariates and Time Dependent Coefficients in the Cox Model*.

Comment: thank you @jmarkow given your comment, i did this analysis but i'm wondering how do we interpret the result ? do we interpret as classical cox analysis ? thank you

Comment: No problem. Depends what analysis you eventually opted for!